# Entity Framework Core: Many-to-Many tables with an order

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have two object tables and a joining table like so:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID
    public ICollection<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeID
    public ICollection<ItemAttribute> ItemAttributes
    public AttributeType Type
    public int ValueID
}

public class ItemAttribute
{
    public int ItemID;
    public Item Item
    public int AttributeID;
    public Attribute Attribute
    public int? Order
}
```

In my OnCreateModelBuilding function, I have the following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasKey(i => i.ItemID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AttributeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemAttribute>()
            .HasKey(ia => new { ia.ItemID, ia.AttributeID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemAttribute>()
            .HasOne<Item>(ia => ia.Item)
            .WithMany(i => i.ItemAttributes)
            .HasForeignKey(ia => ia.ItemID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemAttribute>()
            .HasOne<Attribute>(ia => ia.Attribute)
            .WithMany(a => a.ItemAttributes)
            .HasForeignKey(ia => ia.AttributeID);
```

While I know most joining tables I see in examples and tutorials do not have an Order column, I would like to have one. Here's an example of what I would be trying to do.

Imagine that I saved an Item of Class Picture and I wanted to list in order (from left to right) the students that were in that picture. Here's what I'm thinking as far as the tables:

```
Items
ItemID
1

Attributes
AttributeID     Type          ValueID
1               Student       1
2               Student       2
3               Student       3

ItemAttribute
ItemID          AttributeID        Order
1               3                  1
1               1                  2
1               2                  3
```

In this example, the ValueID is going to point be used to pull the Student information from the StudentRepository. Ideally, I'd like to add the Attributes to the Item and not the other way around. Hence I have this function in the Item class:

```
    public bool AddAttribute(Attribute attribute, int? order)
    {
        ItemAttribute itemAttribute = new ItemAttribute() { Item = this, Attribute = attribute, Order = order != null ? order : null };

        if (ItemAttributes.Contains(itemAttribute))
            return false;

        ItemAttributes.Add(itemAttribute);

        return ItemAttributes.Contains(itemAttribute);
    }
```

Is this the best way to handle this?

Comment: it's not clear. what is your question? and what issue?

Comment: @Asherguru I want to order the items in the joining table. I have found no examples online that suggests the best way to do this. Is the way I provided an ok way to do it, a horrible way to do it, or is there a better way to do it?